# R: Compare a column of a data.table with a vector

Tags: r, compare, data.table

I have a column of a data.table:

```
DT = data.table(R=c(3,8,5,4,6,7))
```

Further on I have a vector of upper cluster limits for the cluster 1, 2, 3 and 4:

```
CP=c(2,4,6,8)
```

Now I want to compare each entry of R with the elements of CP considering the order of CP. The result

```
DT[,NoC:=c(2,4,3,2,3,4)]
```

shall be a column NoC in DT, whose entries are just the number of that cluster, which the element of R belongs to.
(I need the cluster number to choose a factor out of another data.table.)

For example take the 1st entry of R: 3 is not smaller than 2 (out of CP), but smaller than 4 (out of CP). So, 3 belongs to cluster 2.

Another exmaple, take the 6th entry of R: 7 is neither smaller than 2, 4 nor 6 (out of CP), but shmaller than 8 (out of CP). So, 7 belongs to cluster 4.

How can I do that without using if-clauses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description this would seem to be the code to deliver the correct answers, but Arun, a most skillful data.tablist, seems to have come up with a completely different way to fit your expectations, so I think there must be a different way of reading your requirements.

```
> DT[ , NoC:= findInterval(R, c(0, 2,4,6,8) , rightmost.closed=TRUE)]
> DT
   R NoC
1: 3   2
2: 8   4
3: 5   3
4: 4   3
5: 6   4
6: 7   4
```

I'm also very puzzled that `findInterval` is assigning the 5th item to the 4th interval since 6 is not greater than the upper boundary of the third interval (6).

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this using *rolling joins*:

```
data.table(CP, key="CP")[DT, roll=-Inf, which=TRUE]
# [1] 2 4 3 2 3 4
```

`roll=-Inf` performs a NOCB rolling join - Next Observation Carried Backward. That is, in the event of value falling in a gap, the next observation will be rolled backward. Ex: 7 falls between 6 and 8. The next value is 8 - will be rolled backward. We simply get the corresponding index of each match using `which=TRUE`.

You can just add this as a column to `DT` using `:=` as you've shown.

Note that this will return the indices *after ordering* `CP`. In your example, `CP` is already ordered, so it returns the result as intended. If `CP` is not already ordered, you'll have to add an additional column and extract that column instead of using `which=TRUE`. But I'll leave it to you to work it out.

Comment: Took me a while to understand how it works but I think I get it now. Kind of like one of the options in Excel's LOOKUP functions.